# How to pass mixins as props and use them in child components using Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I have a parent component which contains two child components called `add` and `edit`, these components have some common properties and i want to use `mixins`, for that i add an object called `mix` to the parent's data object and i pass it as `props` to child components as follow

the parent component :

```
  <template>
      <div id="app">
       <add :mixin="mix" operation="add"></add>
        ...
        <edit :mixin="mix"  operation="edit"></edit>
     </div>
  </template>  

  <script>
   export default {
        name: "App",
       data(){
          return{
          /****/
            mix:{
              data() {
                  return {
                     user: { name: "", email: "" },
                     users: []
                };
              },
              methods: {
                add() {
                   this.users.push(this.user);
                     },

                    }
                  }
                }
           /*****/
               };
              },
     components: {
         add,edit
    }
     };
   </script>
```

I could receive that object (`mix`) in my child component, but how could i assign it to the `mixins` property?

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is possible to do in Vue. Why do you need to do it like this anyway?

Comment: @HusamIbrahim my components have  some common properties , and i need to create mixins to reuse code

Comment: What I meant was why don't you create the mixin and use it in both components statically instead of passing it as a prop? Do you need to mutate your component definition dynamically at run-time?

Comment: what do you mean by 'statically',  i don't want to write the code twice

Comment: If that's the only objective then refactor your code. Write the mixin in a different file and import it into both components and assign it to the mixins property.

Comment: yes i'm thinking at that solution, thanks my bro, you could post an answer

Comment: Okay. It got me thinking though if this could be done using a `beforeCreate` hook or render function to swap the mixin object dynamically at run-time. Big fan of your answers btw. Learned quite a few things from them. Maybe someday I'll be as well-versed in Vue as you are :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181024/discussion-between-boussadjra-brahim-and-husam-ibrahim).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A low hanging fruit kind of way to solve this would be to just refactor your code and write the mixin in a separate file. You can then import the mixin object in both of your components and assign it to the mixins property.